# Wordpress - Set up a good development and test environment

Tags: php, wordpress, security

Regarding best practices for Development/production environments:

Would it be better to create two sub-domains, perhaps protected by a page that requires a password and if the password is correct then you can enter the dedicated environment?

But this being online, could it not create some problems in Google's indexing? Does Wordpress enable the setting to discourage search engines from finding this site?

Do you have other methods?
I accept advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use subdomains for this.

- Example.com
- staging.example.com
- dev.example.com

Password protect staging and dev. You can set your robots.txt to tell google not to index staging and dev. Many of the SEO plugins like Yoast can handle that for you too.

There are also a number of settings you might want to change based on the environment. Check out [This WP SO question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/350008/best-practice-differences-in-db-options-and-wp-config-between-live-staging-and/350241#350241) for some of the settings you might want to change.

Comment: then my thought was correct, I thought of setting up a pure php login, leaning on another database so that for both the test and development environment if you want to log in, you need to go through this authentication.